# How to set categoryAxis.weekStartDay in Line chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using trial version of `Kendo` UI chart. I was set baseunit ster as "Week". But I have to set wekStartday as Monday. Because in KendoUI by default set to Sunday as start week.

In document suggest that `Kendo` UI has property `categoryAxis.weekStartDay`. But I am not able to find this. So, please help me how to set WeekStartDay as Monday instead of Sunday.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide your DLL and kendo.js version ?

Comment: JS Version : Kendo UI Complete v2013.1.514 and DLL version: 2013.1.514.340.

Answer (score 1):

Please set integer value from 0 to 6 in weekStartDay property.

For Ex:

```
 categoryAxis: {
            baseUnit: "weeks",
            weekStartDay: 1,
            categories: [

                        ]
        }
```

For more information please check below link.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.weekStartDay

Comment: Yes, I already read the Kendo UI document for Set the WeekStartDay property in line chart. But When I tried to set this property then gives the error 

"Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ChartDateCategoryAxisBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'weekStartDay' and no extension method 'weekStartDay' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ChartDateCategoryAxisBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Here is MVC code to generate the graph..

@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
    .Name("chart")                      
               .Series(series => { series.Column(model => model.RevenueValue).Name("Test"); })
               .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                            .Date()
                            .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Weeks)
                            .Categories(model => model.DateValue)                            
                            )
            .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
                .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}"))
            )            
)